# Using QR decomposition to solve least squares in Matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares, qr-decomposition

I am using Matlab to estimate a regression model with ordinary least squares (OLS).

The model is `y = xB`, where `x` is a very sparse matrix with dimension `500000 x 2500`. I'm using a QR decomposition:

```
[C,R] = qr(x,y,0)
```

and then estimating `b` with

```
b = R\C
```

My question is whether I need to be worried about numerical errors here. Is there some additional iteration I need to do? Should I check the condition number of `R`, or `R'R`? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The matlab recommended way is:

`b = X\y;`

Check http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html and section **More About** in particular, to see how matlab handles different cases under the hood.

If you want to exploit the sparseness of X simply declare X as sparse, `X = sparse(X)`, before the call `\`.